# WP_Query() not filtering posts for category

Tags: wp-query

I'm trying to create a custom page for a WordPress theme, which is a child theme of the Twenty Twenty theme. I'm simply trying to use `WP_Query()` to filter out posts so that it only displays posts with the category slug `locations`, however it produces two issues.

1.) It does not filter out the posts, and shows posts in any category.

2.) The error Notice:

> Undefined offset: 9 in /Users/g/Documents/MAMP/childtheme/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 3271 repeats over and over with increasing offsets numbers until the browser crashes.

```
$q = new WP_Query( array('category_name' => 'locations' ));

if ( $q->have_posts() ) {

    while ( $q->have_posts() ) {

        the_post();
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_type() );

    }
}
```

I have a feeling it's something silly, but I have been at it for a few hours and haven't found the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need only the function `the_post();` to map to your custom loop `$q`, like `$q->the_post();` and the filter should run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`the_post()` operates on the main query, but this isn't the main query you're looping over, you need to use `$q->the_post()`

Remember:

- `the_post()` is the same as `global $wp_query; $wp_query->the_post();`
- All post loops are `WP_Query` post loops if you dig down deep enough, even `get_posts` has a `WP_Query` inside it
- There can only be 1 current post in `$post`, calling `the_post` sets that global variable.

This is what a standard post loop should look like:

```php
$args = [
    // parameters go here
];
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) { 
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        // display the post
        the_title();
        the_content();
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    esc_html_e( 'no posts were found', 'textdomain' );
}
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks. But I'm still a bit confused as to why. I'm assuming $q->have_posts() is pulling only posts that register "true" with the WP_Query Parameters (category_name = "locations"), so is it that once it registers true, it needs $q->the_post() in order to tell wordpress to show posts that meets these parameters?

Comment: `the_post` always sets the current post from the main query. `$q` is not the main query. `Remember `the_post()` is the same as `global $wp_query; $wp_query->the_post();`